# Disable user interaction to current page

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin forms application I want to disable the user interaction to current page when displaying a custom popup. How can I block user interaction to the toolbar also. User cannot touch the toolbar when showing the default alert box using the following method

> DisplayAlert(...);
>   But i am using a custom popup. Please help me.

Comment: How did you implement your custom popup? DialogFragment?

Comment: I am using a Grid for custom popup within the page.Display is handled by Isvisible property.

Comment: You could of course just deactivate every button and so on manually while you are displaying your grid, but i'd recommend using the DialogFragment instead, because this is a more common way to do it and it will behave like your typical dialog (Locking interactions etc.). You should be able to inflate some xml with your grid in the DialogFragment. More on that topic [from the xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_3_-_specialized_fragment_classes/#Displaying_a_Fragment).

Comment: DialogFragment is for Xamarin Android. My app is Xamarin.Forms

Comment: My bad, sorry. Try using the [PushModalAsync](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushModalAsync(Xamarin.Forms.Page)/)-method to display another page as a modal dialog. Inside of that page, you can display your grid.

Comment: I want to have it like a popup modal dialog box which will appear above the parent page. PushmodalAsync it opens up a separate page and previous page is not viewable.

Comment: Perhaps have your popup use a transparent background (or light grey)? which gives the effect of a modal.

Comment: Please share some code

Answer (score 1):

this.Content.IsEnabled = false;

It would turn off touch for all the content.

Answer (score 0):

The most MVVM way would be to bind the IsEnabled property to a boolean value in your viewModel. On showing the popup you could toggle the value to false and then revert on dismissing the popup:

```
var label = new Label();
label.setBinding<ViewModel>(Label.IsEnabledProperty, vm=>vm.IsEnabledToggle);
```

Comment: Although this is a valid solution, I believe that its hard work (to write and maintain).  The more controls you have the more you need to write.

Comment: I would suggest making use of Base classes and inheritance to get around the issue of code duplication. This is a relatively common requirement so could be well justified in a custom sublass of a VisualElement derived control.